# Floating point calculation results in a wrong number

Tags: c

I have the following piece of code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int hours;
    float check, phw;
    printf("How many hours worked?");
    scanf(" %d", &hours);
    printf("How much do you make an hour?");
    scanf(" %2f", &phw);
    
    check = phw * (float)hours;
    printf("You have made $%.2f\n", check);
    return 0;
}
```

When entering

> How many hours worked? 24
>
> How much do you make an hour? 7.79

I expect it to come out to `186.96` but I get:

> You have made $168.00
>
> Program ended with exit code: 0

I don't know what I did wrong, I just started learning C so any help is appreciated.

Comment: @BlueMoon - can you explain that?

Comment: 24*7 = 168
24*0,79 = 18,96

168 + 18,96 = 186,96 

 may you see your error now

Comment: @BlueMoon That is incorrect, as long as one of the operands is floating point, the expression will be floating point. Changing int to float won't change anything in this code.

Comment: Hours holds 7, since it is an int. I don't understand your point to be honest. The problem here was that the parsing of the *other* value was wrong, not that hours was an int, and changing hours to be float as well would not actually fix the problem the person was having.

Comment: There's no indication that he wants to read the hours as a floating point value. His code is using int, he's parsing text using %d, and he gives an example with a whole number. The **question**, and let's not forget what the OP came here asking for help with, is why his calculation is wrong. It isn't wrong, he parsed the **other** value incorrectly, so let's help him solve that. I completely agree that a better forward-looking solution is *probably* to make hours into a float but that is **completely orthogonal to his question and problem**.

Comment: Since you said "change hours to float too" *and nothing else* I too would take your comment as "this will help you with your problem". If you wanted to start a general discussion about how to improve his code, you probably should've mentioned that that was your goal.

Comment: Your comment did not provide **anything** related to the solution. The problem was not with the hours variable at all. Changing it to float would not help. He would still have the problem. The 7.79 was the phw variable. I did not say your comment was bad, I was just saying that it did not help solve the problem of why the calculation seemingly gave the wrong results. As such, changing hours to float is incorrect in terms of answering the question in any way. However, this discussion is pointless.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
scanf(" %2f", &phw);
```

Should be changed into

```
scanf(" %f", &phw);
```

[Here](http://ideone.com/F5gAbI) is a working example.

Comment: +1 Correct and with a good example. - Could you explain why this fixes the program? Not being a c expert, I reckon that `scanf(" %2f", &phw)` will strip the decimals from the input number because `%2f` is the format for a 2 digit number without decimals.

Comment: this was perfect! thank you. Along with Rikayan Bandyopadhyay's explanation I understand exactly what I did wrong.

Answer (score 2):

`scanf(" %2f", &phw);` reads two characters max. So `7.79` is read as `7.`

Change to `scanf(" %4f", &phw);` or `scanf(" %f", &phw);`

See [this](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/scanf/) for reference.

Comment: `scanf` provides a lot of options to work with. You can see the link I provided. Anyways, welcome to the site.